# intellij "object index is not a member of package views.html"

Tags: intellij-idea

I've got Intellij 15.0.5 and I cannot get rid of this error

```
object index is not a member of package views.
```

I've created a new play project in Intellij and also using the activator command

```
activator new PlayTestProject
```

But I keep getting the above error. I've read all the other similar question on SO but none of them helped and I've tried the following

1. Right click the project -> Add framework support -> select "Play 2"

Result: I didn't see any change to my project. When I hit OK, the window disappears but if I try the same the second time. Nothing happens and the window is still there!

2. Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Play2 -> select "Use Play 2 compiler for this project"

Result: I get this error

```
Error:Module 'client' production: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I've tried

- invalidate cache & restart
- sbt clean
- checkout a fresh new project

But I keep getting the same error in Intellij.

Running `sbt compile` on command line runs the build successful. But Intellij keeps shows me the above error.

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alright if anyone is running into the same problem. The fix was to mark the following two directories as `Sources Roots` in Intellij.

- /target/twirl/main
- /target/routes

Steps:

1. Right click the `target` folder -> `Mark directory as` -> `Cancel exclusion` (If you don't see `Cancel exclusion` do the next step.
2. Right click the `target/scala-2.11/twirl/main` folder -> `Mark directory as` -> `Sources Root`
3. Right click the `target/scala-2.11/routes` folder -> `Mark directory as` -> `Sources Root`
4. Right click the project `Open module settings` -> `Sources` -> and remove the above two directories if there are added in the `Excluded folder`'s section.

This fixed my problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I could run a play 2 app configuration from IntelliJ just fine, but building, or doing any SBT tasks, gave an error like that. Following these steps, removed the error, and made sbt:run available, and working. I can now rebuild, and run my application with sbt tasks from IntelliJ

Comment: While this does remove the error, I don't think it actually is a solution. After doing this, IntelliJ navigates the `index` method to the compiled class in `target` instead to the actual template.

Comment: Some classes are created when you run the project, try to rebuild your project and run again.

Answer (score 5):

I found this problem and it appeared to be caused by an incomplete compile within sbt. (I had done "sbt clean ; sbt compile" but then aborted the compile with Ctrl+C because it had a error.)

Intellij worked correctly again after I ran:

`sbt clean`

Comment: For me, the solution was to acutally build the project on the command line (`sbt compile`). This created the necessary `target/scala-x.xx/twirl` directory which was then correctly interpreted by IntelliJ.

Comment: Yes, refreshing the project on the command line with sbt (clean and compile) helped with me too.

Comment: Plus 1 for `sbt compile`. I had an invalid route, which was only caught from `sbt compile`

Answer (score 1):

After removing the .idea/ folder, I could successfully re-open/import my project, and the errors were gone.

Comment: Great idea!  I changed several things trying to configure and probably created a bad environment. Removing .idea fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `@()` from top of `index.scala.html` because there are no parameters.

```
@()
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

And in `Action` you have

```
def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.index())
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar error and just had to run `npm install` to fetch the necessary dependencies. Listing it here in case anyone has the same issue.

Comment: how is this related to a scala project?