# IntelliJ Play - object index is not a member of package views.html

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

I'm trying out IntelliJ ultimate and when I create a new play project it does not build with the following error

```
object index is not a member of package views.html
```

There is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447560/intellij-object-index-is-not-a-member-of-package-views-html)

But I don't see any of the directories mentioned.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scala files (views) were not compiled. That's why the directories show up as red.

The views can be compiled manually:

activator compile

make IntelliJ

But of course there's no reason to do this manually.
Just go to

```
Settings/Language and Frameworks/Play
```

and check `Use Play 2 compiler for this project`

And then Make the project